# How do I make an interstitial Ad show every hour?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am currently using **AdMob's Interstitial ads** and I was wondering how can I only show one Ad every one hour or longer. 
I tried configuring this in the Ad Unit settings in AdMob but after the Ad would only load once and show, then once I quit the app and re-opened it. I would only get a black screen. I assume this is because I said to only show one per hour.

I am not sure what to do and I am assuming that I need to put some sort of timer inside my Swift code instead.

Here is what I have so far.

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-1316083366638401/4665490826")
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(15), execute: {
        if self.interstitial.isReady {
            self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        } else {
            print("ad not ready")
        }
   })
}
```

Comment: dont set ad frequency in code, must set in setting of google admob ad setting.. this behavior should not be happen on live

Comment: So when the app goes live, meaning I set the frequency inside AdMob, I then should not see a black screen load in? @ShauketSheikh

Comment: yes.. its only test ads